# form validation not working as intended

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a form with a few fields and a submit button on a webpage. If the fields are empty when the submit button is pressed, a small message is to appear below every field left blank, to prompt the user to fill the respective field. However, when i click the button with, say every field blank, i can see the message displayed only for a split second, after which the top of the web page is shown, of which this form is a part of.

HTML

```
<div class = "contacts">
        <div class = "container-fluid">
            <center><text><b>Contact Me!</b></text></center>
            <center><form role="form">
                <div class = "form-group">
                    <label for="inputname"></label>
                    <input type ="text" class = "form-control" id = "inputname" placeholder = "Name" >
                    <span></span>
                </div>


                <div class = "form-group">
                    <label for="inputemail"></label>
                    <input type ="email" class = "form-control" id = "inputemail" placeholder = "Email Address"  >
                    <span></span>
                </div>


                <div class = "form-group">
                    <label for="inputphone"></label>
                    <input type ="number" class = "form-control" id = "inputphone" placeholder = "Phone Number" >
                    <span></span>
                </div>


                <div class = "form-group">
                    <label for="inputmessage"></label>
                    <textarea type ="text" class = "form-control" id = "inputmessage" rows = "5" placeholder = "Message" ></textarea>
                    <span></span>
                </div>

            <div class = "form-group">
                <center><button type="submit">SEND</button></center>
            </div>
        </form></center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery scipt

```
$(".contacts button").click ( function () {
                    $("form").submit (function () {
                        if ($ ("#inputname").val() === "") {
                            $("span").text("*Enter your name please!").show();

                        }

                        if ($ ("#inputmail").val() === "") {
                            $("span").text("*Enter your email id please!").show();

                        }

                        if ($ ("#inputphone").val() === "") {
                            $("span").text("*Enter your phone number please!").show();

                        }

                        if ($ ("#inputmessage").val() === "") {
                            $("span").text("*Enter your message please!").show();

                        }

                    });
                });
```

what should i change/add to the code to make it work and keep the messsge displayed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any error in browser console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the submission of the page is triggering a reload of the page.

You need to prevent the default form submit, if the values are invalid.

Also there is no need to have a click and submit handler

```js
$("form").submit(function() {
  var valid = true,
    fields = {
      inputname: '*Enter your name please!',
      inputemail: '*Enter your email id please!',
      inputphone: '*Enter your phone number please!',
      inputmessage: '*Enter your inputmessage please!',
    };

  $.each(fields, function(key, value) {
    var $field = $('#' + key),
      blank = $.trim($field.val()) === '',
      $span = $field.next('span');
    if (blank) {
      $span.text(value).show()
    } else {
      $span.hide();
    }
  })

  return valid;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contacts">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <center>
      <text><b>Contact Me!</b>
      </text>
    </center>
    <center>
      <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputname"></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputname" placeholder="Name">
          <span></span>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputemail"></label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputemail" placeholder="Email Address">
          <span></span>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputphone"></label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputphone" placeholder="Phone Number">
          <span></span>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputmessage"></label>
          <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="inputmessage" rows="5" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
          <span></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <center>
            <button type="submit">SEND</button>
          </center>
        </div>
      </form>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! The output is as desired but all the messages are the same. like for the input field it should come as "enter name pls", for the email id as "enter email id pls" etc. Instead all the fields show "enter name pls" only